# Почему неправильно определяется размер экрана при @media-запросе?

Tags: css, запрос, media

Использую специальную вкладку консоли Toggle devise toolbar. При респонсиве экран 320-480 пикселей срабатывает медиа-запрос для экранов от 768-991 пикселей. Помогите найти проблему, 
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" - имеется, стиль кода в SCSS формате
Код:

```
*Основной SСSS код*

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .menu {
    width: 30%;
    nav {
        margin: 50% auto 0 20%;
    }
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .menu {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: `initial-scale=1` есть? страницу не зумили?

Comment: не сработало, при масштабировании страницы тоже ничего

Comment: приложите разметку head, проверил SCSS стили - они работают корректно

Comment: <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title> </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/main.css">
    </head>

Answer (score 0):

Лишняя и не закрытая фигурная скобка. По этому и не работало.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]